How to remove or hide "Chrome extensions work in Microsoft Edge" banner when visiting Chrome Webstore?
Problem
When I visit Chrome Webstore, there's always a large banner informing me that "Chrome extensions work in Microsoft Edge". I know that you can click that close button, but it only removes the banner temporarily - the banner will be shown again after URL hash changes. Is there a simple way to remove or hide the banner?
Screenshot of the banner (Chinese)
Reason

I am already aware of that feature, and I don't need Edge to tell me again and again
The banner really takes a lot of space

Attempts
First, I tried to remove it using devtools. It doesn't work, since the banner is not injected into the page, and you simply can't inspect it.
After googling around for some time, I only found this post on reddit that describes my problem. However, the commandline option --disable-features=msCWSFeatureGroup, as given by @atlanto1979, does not work anymore.
I have also searched edge's group policy on EdgePolicyManager, using keywords like campaign and banner, but found nothing useful for my case.
Specification
I'm using Edge 131.0.2903.51 on Windows 11 23H2, 22631.4460.
